# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' when from tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq import Helper is used

Tags: python, tensorflow

The title may be similar to other posts, but what I ask here is specific and not yet answered by anyone. So I need your help

I get the following error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib`
when I try

`from tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq import Helper`

I've installed tensorflow-addons.
`from tensorflow_addons.seq2seq import Helper` is not working either

**I need to import Helper from seq2seq**

What should I do?

My tensorflow version is 2.2.0

My tensorflow-addons version is 0.11.2

Comment: ```tensorflow.contrib``` functionality has moved to the core after version 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf.contrib doesn't exist in tensorflow 2.x and it is only partialy moved to the tensorflow addons as mentioned here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31350#issuecomment-566151053

Have you tried installing tensorflow 1.15 and re-running the code?

Comment: I'm using python 3.8, People said tensorflow 1.15 doesn't work in python 3.8 in other answers. So I tried installing tensorflow-addons also, but I'm unable to proceed

Comment: It seems you are right, TF1.15 is not supported in python 3.8. If you use conda / docker you could create an environment with python 3.7 which should still support the tensorflow 1.15 version. With conda you can create an environment with: `conda create -n tf python=3.7`